# Why wont Get-WindowsUpdate run via Invoke-Command but locally?

Tags: windows, powershell

following piece of Powershell script:

```
$TargetServer = 'Win10Test'

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $TargetServer -Credential administrator -Scriptblock {Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
Get-WindowsUpdate}
```

spits out this error:

```
Import modules: The file "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSWindowsUpdate\2.2.0.3\PSWindowsUpdate.psm1" cannot be loaded because script execution is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies (https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170).
ObjectNotFound: The command "Get-WindowsUpdate" was found in the module "PSWindowsUpdate", but the module could not be loaded. If you want more information, run "Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate".
```

- ran locally on the target maschine successfully

```
Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
Get-WindowsUpdate
```

- confirmed the presence of the module on the target maschine at *C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSWindowsUpdate\2.2.0.3\PSWindowsUpdate.psm1*
- ran `start winrm` locally on target
- ran `winrm quickconfig` locally on target
- ran `Enable-WuRemoting -Verbose` locally on target
- ran `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` for a short test locally on target
- tried on my machine successfully:

```
$TargetServer = 'Win10Test'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $TargetServer -Credential administrator -Scriptblock {Get-Process}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must ensure that execution of script files (which includes *module* script files, `.psm1`) is permitted on the target machine, which the machine's currently effective [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies)  prevents.

In the simplest case, place a [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) call that effects a *process-level override* at the start of your remotely executing script block:

```bash
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $TargetServer -Credential administrator -Scriptblock {

  # Allow script execution in this process.
  Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass -Force 

  # Now script-based modules are allowed to run.
  Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
  Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
  Get-WindowsUpdate

}
```

Note:

- **Caveat**: If the target machine's execution policy is controlled via *GPOs* (Group Policy Objects), ad-hoc overrides cannot be used - your only option then is to change the GPO-based policy to allow script execution.
- Otherwise, to solve this problem *persistently*, configure the execution policy for the `LocalMachine` scope on the target machine to allow script execution; the `RemoteSigned` policy strikes a good balance between convenience and security (allows local and network-based scripts to run; prevents running scripts downloaded via web browsers, emails and chat clients):

  ```bash
  # One-time action on the target machine.
  # REQUIRES ELEVATION (run as admin):
  Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine RemoteSigned -Force
  ```

Comment: this sir, was the solution for my problem.
Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer. When my rep is >=15 im coming back to vote you up.